# Run executable directly from PHP script with parameters

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Let's say I have an executable PHP file that is usually run like this:

```
php somefile -d someParameter --verbose
```

How can I run this file using an existing PHP script? I am not looking into doing `shell_exec('php somefile -d someParamter --verbose')` since many webhosts disallow the use of shell_exec.

I am thinking something like using `require('somefile')` and then magically passing in the parameters needed for the command to run.

Comment: What is the problem when you use `include` or `require` to load the PHP script?

Comment: What's the task of this `somefile`?

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting does not allow `shell_exec` nor `exec` then you cannot run any external binaries. And it's always common practice to sandbox vhost content so if they would not block `shell_exec`/`exec` you may be hosted from `noexec` mounted volume anyway, so sidede "loaded" binaries would not work either. If you need to run 3rd party binaries, VPS is the way to go, not shared hosting.

Comment: Well, I guess this is partically correct. Although you cannot run the actual PHP file like so `php somefile.php` you can still require it, and then modify `$argv` at least, thats my current workaround.

Comment: I am talking about **external** binaries, which means anything non-PHP. `require()` makes no difference in that case (unless I misunderstood your approach).